# Actionbar style not applied

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have this style.xml

```
 <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
         <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_sliding_menu</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/main</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomTitleColorBar</item>
    </style>
```

I have applied in Manifest following:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
```

In my activity this code

```
ActionBar mSupportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            mSupportActionBar.setTitle("Overview");
```

The problem is the actionbar does not use the background color or any other of the defined changes.

Comment: Try use `name="actionBarStyle"`,`name="background"`..., the problem is with style xml.

Comment: shall I remove "android:"? I did this already nothing happens. I think the problem is with appcompat

Comment: for background ,actionBarStyle yes in my case it's working without android

Answer (score 1):

This one worked in my case i had to write both android:   and without android:  .This is my example i used

```
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

  <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/dim_40</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/dim_40</item>

</style>
 <bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">#ff9800</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

 </style>
```

give it a go and check

Comment: Thx but it does not change anything. Also if I change the Theme to dark it stays all grey.

Comment: I found the  problem, I have different style.xml v11, v12, v14. What does it do?